# How do I make a div appear when I type something

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to make a thing so when I type the word "plz" into a input, a div box will appear. But I can't quite figure it out. I think it has something to do with javascript.

My code is

```
<html>
  
  <style>
    
    .boxR{
      
        width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
        background-color:black;
        color:red;
        font-size:100px;
        font-weight:700;
        visibility:hidden;
      
    }
    
  </style>
  <body>
    
    <center>
      
          <br>
      
          <div class = "boxR"><br>hello</div>
          
          <input id = "test">
      
    </center>
    
    <script>
    
    while(true){
      
      sleep(10)
      
      if(document.getElementById("test").value == "plz"){
        document.getElementById("boxR").visibility = visible
      }}
      
    </script>
    

    
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what I did wrong?

Comment: None of the answers below mention it, but you definitely want to get rid of the `while` loop. Javascript already has it's own event loop and you never need to create your own.

Comment: Also, `sleep` doesn't exist in javascript.   Think in terms of event triggers, not polling loops.

Answer (score 0):

At

```
if(document.getElementById("test").value == "plz"){
        document.getElementById("boxR").visibility = visible
}}
```

You didn't set the style attribute `visiblity` to visible. Change the `document.getElementById("boxR").visibility = "visible"` to `document.getElementById("boxR").style.visibility = "visible"`

Changing any element's style in JavaScript, you must reference it like this:
`element.style.attribute = value`

Corrected code:

```
window.onkeyup = () => {
  if(document.getElementById("test").value == "plz"){
        document.getElementById("boxR").visibility = visible
  }}
}
```

You can change the type of event listener to limit the scope (like the specific element), that way you won't be checking for unnecessary things.

Comment: This doesn't answer the part of the question about "when the user types something", and also doesn't correct the error where the value "visible" is unquoted

Comment: Oh, yes I see, I guess I only caught the part of setting the visiblity.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a snippet that demonstrates the desired behavior.

One of your problems was with not putting quotes around "visible". Another one was in trying to call `sleep`, which you can't do because JavaScript is single-threaded and thus this would lock up the browser.

```js
//while(true){
      
//      sleep(10)
//}
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
//  console.log("key");
  if (e.target.value.includes("plz")) {
    document.querySelector("div").classList.remove("invis");
  } else document.querySelector("div").classList.add("invis");
});

      if(document.getElementById("test").value == "plz"){
        document.getElementById("boxR").visibility = "visible"
      }
```

```css
    .boxR{
      
        width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
        background-color:black;
        color:red;
        font-size:100px;
        font-weight:700;
      
    }

.invis {
  visibility : hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
 
  <body>
    
    <center>
      
          <br>
      
          <div class = "boxR invis">
          <br>hello
          </div>
          
          <input id = "test" >
      
    </center>
    

    
  </body>
</html>
```